# Not able to login using jmeter - Have followed almost all guide available on stack overflow and internet

Tags: regex, jmeter

Code is:

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="Yekn8BJNbXaydRs8yq1GEmDogsFoSh8AGyOKmjLn0zFvhmADPYrqU43/foLoEzJk4yEeNSg78pCIJh6uxuyWf9foM7VsZayC2trOXwUA2hyUWSAf9mBC8vN60ccAVki37fC1LNHhAlDkthgmsM3WNxJwvVGWMj2TMqoONGI0aj5b2hJkQMMClKx0zhthqtD8" />
```

My Jmeter config. is given below as screenshot :

[image: Extracting Expression]

[image: Post Data]

What is incorrect I did here :( It is not logging & giving error : **Object moved to here**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why you [shouldn't use regular expressions for parsing HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748): one of the reasons is that HTML-oriented regular expressions would be very fragile and sensitive to any line-break, space, tags order, etc.

So the options are:

1. [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor). Relevant config would be:

   - CSS/JQuery Expression: `input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]`
   - Attribute: `value`
2. [XPath Extractor](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0). Configure it as follows:

   - XPath Expression: `//input[@name='__RequestVerificationToken']/@value`
   - if your response is not XML/XHTML-compliant you'll also need to check `Use Tidy (tolerant parser)` box

Comment: Thanks , Let me use this.

Comment: I have invited you in chat can you please reply there as I am facing still issue with login.

Answer (score 2):

In your regular expression extractor, your regular expression needs to be

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="(.+?)"
```

instead of what you have now.  It should work once you change that.

Comment: If this worked, please mark as answer @Helping Hands

Comment: Should I put with input tag? in regular expression?

Comment: Yes put exactly what the code is showing because that's the pattern the regex extractor will look for.  It needs to be exactly like the code, with the part you want to extract within the parenthesis.

Comment: It will work either way. @HelpingHands It doesn't need it.  Because it will go until it finds the " at the end of the token.

Comment: Hey I tried in all way but still getting ERROR for __RequestVerificationToken :(